# How to restrict connection to database using IP

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Hi Experts
How I can restrict connection to my database(in sql server 2005) according to IPs in network?
Consider that I want to my database just accept connection from my computer an a specific Server.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the article which exactly matches your criteria. [IP Address blocking](http://sql-articles.com/blogs/ip-address-blocking-or-restriction-in-sql-server/)

Comment: Link is dead. :(

Answer (score 0):

Consider three layers:

WebApp :: Server :: Database

Make a table on your db with a list of banned IPs.
For whatever language you are using (PHP/Java/etc..), you can check the users IP address first. Make a call to the db... something like:

SELECT ip FROM ip_ban_table WHERE ip = {your_parameter}

If it returns null, you are good to go. Otherwise, you know that the user is on your blocked list.

This may not scale so well, you might want to put this check right before you actually do anything with your db... but this would all be on your server-side code.